# Firefox improperly renders svg background with opacity and background-size: cover

Tags: css, svg, firefox

I stumbled upon a weird issue in firefox (MacOS) where opacity is not applied for an SVG background image that is used in :before pseudo-element with background-size cover or higher values than 100%.

In Chrome, the SVG is rendered in the background with 0.05 opacity applied as expected.

In Firefox 98.0.1 on MacOS, it is rendered as black as if no opacity is applied at all. What is weird though is that if I change the background-size to 50% for instance, it is rendered properly. What's more, if I toggle the opacity rule in firebug it renders as expected.

Is it a firefox bug or am I missing something? Any ideas for a workaround?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/wolasso/pen/RwxobEo

Expected result (Chrome, Safari):

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

```css
.test {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #4C8CB8;
}

.test:before {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  opacity: 0.05;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Firefox on my Windows10 laptop renders the opacity OK.

Comment: I have Firefox 98.0.1 on MacOS and your testcase displays correctly. What version of MacOS are you running?

Comment: @RobertLongson I am running 10.14.3. Please open the codepen and tinker with background-size property so that the SVG is covering most of the viewport. I noticed that the bug does not appear when the SVG is rendered small in comparison with the viewport

Comment: I'm on 12.3 It seems to work fine whatever I do.